# React useState to return a fake image with two different conditions

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, buttonclick, react-functional-component

When the two buttons are false, they return the same image, but they are next to each other, how can I make the test3 image equal for both states without having to insert another image?

```
 const [b1State, setB1State] = useState(false);
 const [b2State, setB2State] = useState(false);

<button onClick={() => {setB1State(!b1State)}}>Test1</button>
<button onClick={() => {setB2State(!b2State)}}>Test2</button>

{b1State ? <img src={test1} alt="" /> : <img src={test3} alt="" />}
{b2State ? <img src={test2} alt="" /> : <img src={test3} alt="" />}
```

The problem is when both buttons are true, and it puts one image above and one below, I believe that when one is true the other should be false.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 possible combination (0 0, 0 1, 1 0, 1 1) of 2 button states - so you need to check all of them.

And which button image to show when both are on? - you need to create a new state variable which stores the lastClicked button.

```
/* These constants contains image url */
const test1 = "full length apron";
const test2 = "waist apron";
const test3 = "naked";

const [b1State, setB1State] = useState(false);
const [b2State, setB2State] = useState(false);
// last clicked option will be displayed when both of them are "true" - so created a new state
const [lastClicked, setLastClicked] = useState(test1);

return(
    <>
        <button onClick={() => {setB1State(!b1State); setLastClicked(test1)}}>Test1</button>
        <button onClick={() => {setB2State(!b2State); setLastClicked(test2)}}>Test2</button>

        {/* when both the button are off - naked guy image appears */}
        { (!b2State && !b1State) && <img src={test3} alt={test3} /> }

        {/* when button 1 is on and 2 is off - full length apron image appears */}
        { (b1State && !b2State) && <img src={test1} alt={test1} /> }

        {/* when button 2 is on and 1 is off - waist apron image appears */}
        { (b2State && !b1State) && <img src={test2} alt={test2} /> }

        {/* when both the buttons are on - last button click image appears */}
        { (b1State && b2State) && <img src={lastClicked} alt={lastClicked} /> }
    </>
);
```

Comment: The problem is when both buttons are true, and it puts one image above and one below, I believe that when one is true the other should be false. ![DEMO IMAGE SAMPLE](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/814619234386051139/850849582211530773/p7.gif).

Comment: Thanks for the demo image @André . I hope now your problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Set to ensure that an image `src` is included once. After creating the Set, spread it back to an array, and render using `Array.map()`:

```js
const { useState, useMemo } = React

const test1 = 'https://picsum.photos/id/237/100'
const test2 = 'https://picsum.photos/id/1003/100'
const test3 = 'https://picsum.photos/id/1024/100'

const Demo = () => {
  const [b1State, setB1State] = useState(false);
  const [b2State, setB2State] = useState(false);

  // create the unique array of images using a Set
  const images = useMemo(() => [...new Set([
    b1State ? test1 : test3,
    b2State ? test2 : test3,
  ])], [b1State, b2State])

  return ( 
    <div>
    <button onClick={() => {setB1State(!b1State)}}>Test1</button>
    <button onClick={() => {setB2State(!b2State)}}>Test2</button>
    
    <br />
      {images.map(src => ( // render the array
        <img key={src} src={src} alt="" />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: The images should change in only one place if it is if b1 is true replaces false and if b2 is true replaces b1 or false the only one left for both is false, thinks the false image is a face and b1 is a cap and b2 is a glasses

Answer (score 1):

You can use this conditional render seperate for img3

```
{(!b1State && !b2State) && <div>show img3</div>}
{b1State && <div>show img1</div>}
{b2State && <div>show img2</div>}
```

Comment: This example works but when I click on the two buttons it puts another image next to it.